# cannot access localhost in wamp server

Tags: apache-http-server, php, wamp

MY wamp server was running ok, though very slow, so googled through to find some solution. Following this link - [WAMP is Running Very Slow](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow).

I run some commands without understanding the implication. WAMP is Running Very Slow

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset C:\resetlog.txt
```

After I restarted the machine, the wamp sever seem to running fine(Green Icon) in system tray, but in browser I am unable to access localhost or any thing.(just getting timeout after some time)

On check port 80 I am getting

```
 ***** Test which uses port 80 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====


Test for TCP
Your port 80 is used by a processus with PID = 11360
The processus of PID 11360 is 'httpd.exe' Session: Services
The service of PID 11360 for 'httpd.exe' is 'wampapache'
This service is from Wampserver - It is correct
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

Your port 80 is not actually used.
```

ok there is one error shown by wampmenu - your virtualhosts. When I click on this I get:

```
Sorry,
```

There is an error.
In the httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
    The number of

            <VirtualHost ...>
    is not equal to the number of

            ServerName
```

They should be identical.

```
    Correct syntax is: <VirtualHost *:80>
```

Switch cancelled

Press ENTER to continue...

UPDATE: I get some logs in Apache-error log:

```
[Sat Feb 18 23:22:10.221512 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7244:tid 548] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sat Feb 18 23:22:12.225007 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7872:tid 452] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sat Feb 18 23:22:12.336354 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7244:tid 548] AH00430: Parent: Child process 7872 exited successfully.
[Sat Feb 18 23:22:14.369397 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 7516:tid 556] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Feb 18 23:22:14.451929 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7516:tid 556] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) PHP/5.6.25 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Feb 18 23:22:14.451929 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7516:tid 556] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:09:37
[Sat Feb 18 23:22:14.451929 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7516:tid 556] AH00094: Command line: 'e:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.23\\bin\\httpd.exe -d E:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23'
[Sat Feb 18 23:22:14.456325 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7516:tid 556] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1876
[Sat Feb 18 23:22:15.294839 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1876:tid 412] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Feb 18 23:22:15.360767 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1876:tid 412] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: Please check your error logs.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Sorry - No error logs. any other pointer?